# How to delete a file if .shp is less than(equal) 100 byte with batch?

Tags: batch-file, filesize

I have a folder Esri shapes. Every shape consists of 5 separate files. (.dbf .prj .qpj .shp .shx)
I want delete 5 separate file if .shp is less than(equal) 100 bytes.

For example if I have the following files:

```
A.dbf
A.prj
A.qpj
A.shp (100byte)
A.shx
B.dbf
B.prj
B.qpj
B.shp (150byte)
B.shx
C.dbf
C.prj
C.qpj
C.shp
C.shx (243byte)
```

Then I want these files as below:

```
B.dbf
B.prj
B.qpj
B.shp
B.shx
C.dbf
C.prj
C.qpj
C.shp
C.shx
```

I don't know much about the code language needed to write a batch file.
I found some code elsewhere on Stackoverflow, but it 100 byte all delete

```bash
@echo off
setlocal
:: Size is in bytes
set "min.size=100"

for /f  "usebackq delims=;" %%A in (`dir /b /A:-D *.*`) do If %%~zA LSS %min.size% del "%%A"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f  "usebackq delims=;" %%A in (`dir /b /A:-D *.shp`) do If %%~zA LEQ %min.size% ECHO del "%%~nA.*"
```

- The `*.shp` makes the `dir` return only those files named `whatever.shp`
- The `ECHO` has been inserted as a safety measure to simply report what files are intended to be deleted. Once you have finished testing, remove the `echo` keyword on that line to actually delete the files reported.
- The `~n` modifier picks just the name part of the file `%%A`
- The `.*` then says `this name - all extensions`.

**Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.**